# Poco linking error when using Poco::NetSSL

Tags: cmake, poco-libraries

First of all, I am quite inexperienced when it comes to cmake, as I have only very recently started using it. I wanted to use POCO simply to send a message to a given email address. The code is uncomplicated and for all intents and purposes, can be seen as an equivalent to the code present in this [example](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/devel/NetSSL_OpenSSL/samples/Mail/src/Mail.cpp) from the poco github. Afterwards, I tried to compile it using cmake, like I had previously done for the rest of my project. Checking online, it seems that adding

```
find_package(Poco REQUIRED COMPONENTS Foundation NetSSL Util XML)
target_link_libraries(PROJECT_NAME PUBLIC Poco::Foundation Poco::NetSSL Poco::Util Poco::XML)
```

should make the cmake run.
However, this leads to the following error

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /usr/local/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoUtilConfig.cmake

  but it set PocoUtil_FOUND to FALSE so package "PocoUtil" is considered to
  be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing: Poco::XML
  Poco::JSON

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoNetSSLConfig.cmake:3 (find_dependency)
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/Poco/PocoConfig.cmake:29 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

I had also attempted to create a secondary empty project, for which I created a different CMakeLists.txt which contains only:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(main)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
find_package(Poco REQUIRED Foundation XML JSON)
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC Poco::Foundation Poco::XML Poco::JSON)
```

Running `cmake .` works on this without issue, but adding Util and Poco::Util seems to always be problematic.
I am not knowledgable enough to fix this issue.
I have installed Poco as described on their website, and ran all cmake related commands on the site. I have also installed OpenSSL using `apt-get install libssl-dev`.
I did not install the ODBC or SQL related dependencies cause they weren't needed, I only wanted to send emails.

Reverting the order of the packages in `find_package` seems to improve the situation:

```
find_package(Poco REQUIRED Foundation XML JSON Util NetSSL)
target_link_libraries(
    PROJECT_NAME PUBLIC Poco::Foundation Poco::JSON Poco::XML Poco::Util Poco::NetSSL
)
```

cmake . now successfully runs, but running make, the percentage never passes 0%, and running the resulting program gives the following error:

```
./PROGRAM_NAME: error while loading libPocoCrypto.so.95: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, this file and all the other libs from Poco are located in the same directory, /usr/local/lib.
Explicitly adding Crypto and Poco::Crypto in the find_package and target_link_libraries did not solve the issues.

Thank you for your time. Any suggestions are apreciated!

Comment: I'm getting the [same issue when trying to build `aur/projectm-sdl2-git`](https://gist.github.com/trinitronx/5f2d45e3f3f23e0ed905fff4d8a82f3e) on Manjaro Linux:  `The following imported targets are referenced, but are missing: Poco::XML
  Poco::JSON`

[Full error](https://gist.github.com/trinitronx/5f2d45e3f3f23e0ed905fff4d8a82f3e#file-output-of-yay-syu-projectm-sdl2-git-L48-L49) says issue is from [line 29 of `CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/projectM-visualizer/frontend-sdl2/blob/9d22a2b35ab65f0bb3e1cb61bb151a2dfa5c518e/CMakeLists.txt#L29). `find_package(Poco REQUIRED COMPONENTS Util)`

Comment: I managed to get `projectm-sdl2-git` to build by [just using a similar line](https://gist.github.com/trinitronx/5f2d45e3f3f23e0ed905fff4d8a82f3e#file-poco-cmakelists-patch) to your `find_package()`, only without the `target_link_libraries` bit:  `find_package(Poco REQUIRED COMPONENTS Foundation XML JSON Util NetSSL)`.  In my case, the built `projectMSDL` binary doesn't seem to crash (as far as I've tested).